MAUI: Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingPurchaseException: Invalid products found when querying product list
I am getting below exception when when I try to pay for a subscription for app store.

Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingPurchaseException: Invalid products found when querying product list
at Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.PurchaseAsync(String productId, ItemType itemType, String applicationUserName)
at Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.PurchaseAsync(String productId, ItemType itemType, String obfuscatedAccountId, String obfuscatedProfileId, String subOfferToken)

I have created 3 subscriptions on the app store and all are in Ready to Submit state.
My Code:
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("");
if (IsBusy)
    return;

IsBusy = true;
try
{
    // check internet first with Essentials
    if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
        return;

    // connect to the app store api
    var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();
    if (!connected)
        return;

    UserDialogs.Instance.HideHud();
    //try to make purchase, this will return a purchase, empty, or throw an exception
    var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.Subscription);

    if (purchase == null)
    {
        //nothing was purchased
        return;
    }

    if (purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Purchase successfull");
        Debug.WriteLine("Purchase token:>>" + purchase.PurchaseToken);
        Debug.WriteLine("Purchase id:>>" + purchase.Id);
        
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InAppBillingPurchaseException(PurchaseError.GeneralError);
    }
}
catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
{
    // Handle all the different error codes that can occure and do a pop up
    Debug.WriteLine("purchaseEx:>>" + purchaseEx);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle a generic exception as something really went wrong
    Debug.WriteLine("exception:>>" + ex);
}
finally
{
    await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
    IsBusy = false;
}

Am I miss any other set up for the proper working of this? Is there any permission do we need on the info.plist? I tested it on simulator, is it work on simulator or do we need to test it on a real device?

Start with this step do we need to test it on a real device plug your iOS device & select Release Mode
